# Java little ball runs away from cursor

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to make a graphic project where a Ball runs away from my cursor, I already did the other way around where the ball seeks my cursor and when she arrives she loses velocity so it's like she's running fast until she comes around a range of 10 pixels and then she loses velocity until she touches the cursor.

The thing is, I can't find a way to make the ball run away from the cursor in a way that when I enter a diameter(from the ball), she runs slow, if I approach more she starts to run faster to get away but when my cursor leaves the diameter, she runs slow until she stops once again.

I hope I made it clear, I thought about a solution but I don't know if there's a library or some built function in Java that I could use guys:
 -have like a percentage from 0 to 100 where the distance between my cursor and the ball fits inside, 0% is velocity=0, 100% is velocity=4 for example, do you have any idea if there is such thing that I could implement?

Thank you in advance!

*I've made a Vector class where I change it and access the X and Y coordinates to make the ball move, I used basic trigonometry to make the vector ALWAYS the same length.*

code of my ball (Chaser) class:

```
public class Chaser {

private double x;
private double y;
private double vel = 1;
private double hyp;

private Vector vector = new Vector(0, 0);

private double distance;

public Chaser(int width, int height){
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;

}

public void setVel(Point m){
    if(m.x != x)
        hyp = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(m.x - x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(m.y - y), 2));
    else
        hyp = Math.abs(m.y - y);
}

public void setDirection(Point m){
    if(hyp == 0) return;
    vector.change((m.x - x)/hyp, (m.y - y)/hyp);
}

public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval((int)x - 10, (int)y - 10, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine((int)x, (int)y, (int)(vector.getX()*15*vel) + (int)x, (int)(vector.getY()*15*vel) + (int)y);
}

public void move(Point m){
    setVel(m);
    setDirection(m);
    useVector();
}

public void useVector(){
    if(vector == null) return;
    x -= vector.getX() * vel;
    y -= vector.getY() * vel;
}

public void calculateVelocity(Point m){
    if(vector == null) return;
    // I don't know what to do yet
}
```

}

Comment: Your `setDirection` method has a semicolon at the end, that shouldn't be there, remove it. `public void setDirection(Point m){ ... };` <- this semicolon.

Comment: @Zabuca thanks didn't notice that!

Comment: "_I can't find a way to make the ball run away from the cursor in a way that when I enter a diameter(from the ball), she runs slow, if I approach more she starts to run faster to get away but when my cursor leaves the diameter, she runs slow until she stops once again._" Well, there is 2 problem here. What could be the formula to get a speed based on the diameter of the ball. Then how the distance between the ball and the cursor could influence the speed. The first is your choice, the second is just a ratio to us based on the distance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just push the ball around you can do something simple. Let's use vectors to make it easier to understand. Say `ball` holds the ball's center (x,y) and `mouse` contains the mouse position (x,y).

You can compute the distance between ball and mouse, that is `(mouse - ball).length()` to get how far away the mouse is from the ball.

If the distance > ball radius then the mouse is outside.

Otherwise you can do:

```
tmp =  ball - mouse  // get the vector from mouse to the ball.
tmp = tmp / tmp.length() * ball_radious  // change the vector's length to match the radious of the ball.
ball = mouse + tmp  // Move the ball such that the mouse will be on the edge.
```

As you move the mouse the ball will get pushed by the mouse.
If you want a bit of inertia, so the ball doesn't just stop when you don't push it anymore then you need to keep an additional vector speed and use tmp to get an acceleration.
Something like this:

```
tmp =  ball - mouse  // get the vector from mouse to the ball.
force = max(0, ball_radious - tmp.length())  // how strong we push the ball.
acceleration = tmp / tmp.legnth() * f(force)  // compute the acceleration vector. f(force) is some function based on force, try k*f or k*f*f and see what looks better for your setup.
speed = speed * kDrag + acceleration  // update the speed, kDrag should be between 0 and 1, start with something like 0.8 and try different values.
ball = ball + speed * time_delta // Update the ball's position.
```

You can play with the constants to get the right feel that you're looking for. time_delta is meant to normalize the speed between frams so you don't need to worry too much if there's some inconsistency between them. You can use a constant as well, but the movement might become jerky at times.

All operations above are vector operations.